Peak FFT Frequency Off By One Bin
I used Excel's FFT feature to compute an FFT of a 440Hz sine wave that I also generated with Excel. The peak FFT value should occur at 440 Hz. Instead, it occurred one bin later at 528 Hz, so I'm binning wrong somehow. What's the issue?

Well I guess you binned everything off by one? Maybe this can help

Thanks for the linked notes. I'm familiar with what they explain. I don't think I binned off by one. My input range row matches my output range row as shown in the notes you linked. I'm thinking of simply shifting the FFT output data up by one row to line things up. This will drop the DC component off the output list and put the first AC component at f = 0, which makes me cringe because...well...the 1st AC component by definition has f !=0. So, what are my options?

The problem seems to stem from the number of bins with data. Originally, I generated a time domain signal with 100 values and padded with zeroes to 128, the next power of 2. This gave me the problem in my question: the peak one bin off from what should've been the peak frequency. There were also other artificial results like non-zero values in many of the other bins. Because I was generating a pure-frequency signal at 440 Hz, 100% of the signal should've been in the 440Hz bin.
When I recreated the time domain signal with 128 values so that I would not have to pad with zeroes, the FFT made sense: the peak occured at 440 Hz with 100% of the signal in that bin and zeroes everywhere else.
I guess one of the takeaways here is that the number of actual data points in the time domain signal should be a power of two and that padding with zeroes to the next power to 2 will cause strange FFT results in Excel.
Happy to hear any comments.

So Data, what's the bin index number for the very first FFT bin that contains the DC component?


Although I defined it as such. Excel only outputs the Complex FFT results not the index. according to the article linked below, those outputs follow the following index order: 0, 1, 2 ... N/2 - 1, -N/2, -N/2 + 1, -N/2 + 2, ..., -2, -1. Here's the article that explains it (Thanks to Jdip for passing it along): https://www.brainmapping.org/NITP/PNA/tests/ProblemSet3_files/FourierExcel.htm


well, then i dunno why you would get an off-by-one error.  I wouldn't expect spectral leakage to do that.  To reduce spectral leakage, try windowing your input data, perhaps even zero-padding after windowing (which means a longer FFT, but that shouldn't hurt you.).

There's a thing called "Fencepost error" or "Off-by-one error" and it's because them folks at Mathworks have apparently never read Dijkstra.
I'm really grumpy about the topic, especially when it comes to the FFT, which is only an efficient method of calculating the DFT.

I agree wholeheartedly with you. MATLAB's lack of a zero-valued index has been a nuisance.

@RichardLyons , it shouldn't just be zero-origin.  If MATLAB was going to allow us to write equations as we do in textbooks and literature, we should also be able to have negative indices.  So each MATLAB array, besides having the number of rows and columns as attributes (that can be known with size() and changed with reshape()), each dimension should have an origin that can be changed and the default origin should be 1 to make this backwards compatible. I had a discussion with Cleve Moler about this more than a quarter century ago. They don't listen.

Interesting read. I'm familiar with fencepost errors, and I appreciate the importance of numbering starting at 0, but I don't see how these comments, while interesting, directly address my issue. I'm using Excel, not MATLAB; and Excel doesn't make explicit use of indexing, so I didn't have a chance to fumble by starting an array at 1, 0 or any other explicit number. @Jdip linked an article in a comment above that gives a nice overview of how Excel does FFT in case you're interested: https://www.brainmapping.org/NITP/PNA/tests/ProblemSet3_files/FourierExcel.htm

So the thing is Data is that MATLAB puts the bin for DC (having a frequency of 0) into the bin with index 1.  And if you use MATLAB max utility to get the index of the peak, you must subtract 1 from the result of max() to get something proportional to frequency without offset.  So you have to figger out how Excel is numbering the bins.
